# How to Dynamically Create Save and Load XAML file in WPF

Tags: wpf, sql-server-2005, c#-4.0

What my Requirement is Dynamically Create a XAML file with WPF and Load That File From the Directory where which is Saved.. From Database am Planning to add Controls to the XAML While Creating File. Is it Possible For Me to Save it in the Compiled Format and Load it at run time. please help me with sample code or Reference..

With regards anish.

Comment: what do you mean by compiled format? have you tried this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ashish/archive/2007/08/14/dynamically-loading-xaml.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 'Save it in the Compiled Format' might be tricky, but you can easily save/load XAML and use the XAML in a WPF app but utilising the XamlReader and XamlWriter classes.
http://fritzenhammer.wordpress.com/2006/08/12/xamlwriter-and-xamlreader-wpf-serialization/